# Light HTML webpage designer to use along side netbeans on my mac?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to know if there is a plugin for netbeans that would make it easy for me to edit html and build simple temp pages while coding so I can place things in the right place on my page etc..

If there isn't a plugin is there any lightweight HTML webpage editor I could use?

I also don't mind buying..

Comment: You can try http://www.pure-mac.com/webed.html and http://www.optima-system.com/pagespinner/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightweight HTML Editor? :O

Try http://brandonsoft.com/htmlide/